# NetTCPIP missing from Get-Modules for one minute

Tags: powershell, networking

Why does `Get-Module` not show all the installed Modules?

Some PCs don't have the NetTCPIP module installed. Mine does, but when I open a new PowerShell ISE window

```
Get-Module | Where-Object Name -eq 'NetTCPIP' | Format-Table
```

**Returns blank.**

After one minute it returns:

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                                                                                     
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                                                                                     
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetTCPIP                            {Find-NetRoute, ...}
```

The strange thing is:

```
Get-Command -Name Test-NetConnection
```

Always shows that the command exists in the Source: NetTCPIP.

Now the even strange thing is that on a Server OS running the same version of PowerShell, never shows the NetTCPIP module but **does** have the command `Test-NetConnection`.

Why does `Get-Module` not show all the installed Modules?

Answer (score 2):

`Get-Module` by default lists only the modules which are currently imported. If you want to see all the modules, you can use `Get-Module -ListAvailable`.

Starting with PowerShell 3.0, modules are [dynamically imported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/importing-a-powershell-module?view=powershell-7#implicitly-importing-a-module-powershell-30) first time you use the cmdlet from that module. So if you test the cmdlet to see if it exists (or you use `Get-Command Test-NetConnection`), PowerShell silently imports the module and it's displayed next time you use `Get-Module`.